# Appended information gets erased when I close my application

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am currently appending a list each time the user enters some values and clicks adds on this page. This information is also sent to the the server each time it is added. It is working fine but the information does not stay there if I close the application.

For example if I go to another page on the same application and revisit this page, the information is still there. But if I were to totally close the application and restart it, the appended information is gone. Is it cos the information I am storing is just staying in ram memory and thus gets erased? I looked around and unable to find any similar cases. Please advice how I can rectify this. Thanks.

```
$('#add_list').click( function() {

        listDescription = $('#list_description').val();
        payment = $('#payment').val();
        $('.expense_list').prepend('<div>' + "\u00A3 "  + listDescription + "\t\t\t" + payment + "\t" + '</div>');
        //end of append

        //sending the expense list information to the server each time it is added.
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com",
            data: {
                amount: listDescription,
                account: payment
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType:'json',
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

        $('#list_form')[0].reset();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: is the data being saved on the server ?

Comment: is your question, why does the data stay until you close the app, or why when you back the data is missing ?

Comment: why the data goes missing when I close application. I want it to remain there when I reopen the application at a later time.

Comment: i dont know how you are building your other pages. since you are starting the app up fresh again you should be rebuilding the data you need, so it should include the new data.

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent the information from disappearing by using localstorage?

Comment: @keshk Ya, if user don't clear cache. Why don't you try it? But i guess you'd have better to reload relevant data from server on each page reload

Answer (score 0):

html-data you are adding with `prepend()` or `append()` to your page is just added to your browser's cache. as soon as you close the browser (or the browser-window / -tab), this information is not longer availabe.

your application is missing an output-module, which renders the output of the information which is stored in your database.

Comment: So I should probably set up a Get method back at the server and retrieve information from the server via getJSON each time the page loads on the application?

Comment: you could do it with ajax GET into JSON and then rendering the html with jQuery/javascript.
but it would be much easier to render all the information which is already saved in your database by using PHP/MySQL only.
so you render the "old" information with PHP (so it's already on the page when you open it) and add the new information with jQuery/ajax.

Comment: i don't know if you are using PHP at all and which kind of MySQL-library you are using if it's about an MySQL-Database at all.
show me more of your code, for example the html-page and the code you are using to save your data to the database and i can help you.